# Why breakpoint location is +4 bytes to the function address?

Tags: macos, debugging, breakpoints, clang++, lldb

Say I have this `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

int foo() {
  return 123;
}

int main() {
  int a = 1234;
  std::cout << foo() + a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Then I compile it:

```
clang++ -g -O0 main.cpp
```

Now I have this `a.out`, which I can look at the symbol table via `dsymutil -s a.out`:

```
...
[    11] 00000001 2e (N_BNSYM      ) 01     0000   0000000100003ce0
[    12] 00000002 24 (N_FUN        ) 01     0000   0000000100003ce0 '__Z3foov'
[    13] 00000001 24 (N_FUN        ) 00     0000   0000000000000008
[    14] 00000001 4e (N_ENSYM      ) 01     0000   0000000100003ce0
...
```

So, this `foo` function is at `3ce0`.

Now, use LLDB to set a breakpoint at this function:

```
% lldb a.out
(lldb) target create "a.out"
Current executable set to '/Users/royshi/tmp/a.out' (arm64).
(lldb) b foo
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`foo() + 4 at main.cpp:4:3, address = 0x0000000100003ce4
(lldb)
```

Now, notice the breakpoint is at `(0x000000010000)3ce4`, and it reads "where = a.out`foo() + 4 at main.cpp:4:3", which agrees with the `3ce4` address.

So apparently the breakpoint is 4 bytes beyond `foo`'s address (`3ce0`).

**I wonder why the 4-byte difference?**

---

**EDIT:**

Following the above, I then tried to remove the dSYM folder (by moving it away), then again setting the breakpoint, it ended up being at `foo`'s address (i.e. no extra 4 bytes). So, it seems to be related to the debug symbols in some way.

```
# moving a.out.dSYM to somewhere unaccessible
% mv a.out.dSYM tmp2

% lldb a.out
(lldb) target create "a.out"
Current executable set to '/Users/royshi/tmp/a.out' (arm64).
(lldb) b foo
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`foo(), address = 0x0000000100003ce0
(lldb) ^D
```

Comment: I would guess that those 4 bytes are setting up the function's stack frame - so that when the breakpoint actually triggers, you can see and modify any local variables that are being stored on the stack.

Comment: In your hypothesis, are the 4 bytes which does the set up generated by the compiler (i.e. an actual part of the original binary), or are they being replaced by lldb (and the original 4 bytes moved somewhere else) *in order to* do this set up?

--

FWIW, see my "EDIT". When I tried without debug symbol (dSYM), the breakpoint is at the function's location. So it seems lldb is behaving differently according to the dSYM's availability, which is still confusing to me.

Comment: It would be generated by the compiler.  I can easily believe that it might be conditional on whether you are compiling for debugging, since your test function has no local variables and therefore doesn't actually need a stack frame.

Comment: But why would lldb put breakpoint at different locations based on whether or not there is debug symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jasonharper got the reason for doing this right.  If you stop at the very start of a function, before the prologue is run and the new stack frame set up, then the stack unwind might not look right, and variable values which are given in terms of the stack after the prologue will be all off. That can be disconcerting if you don't know what's going on.  So by default, when you set a breakpoint on a function symbol, lldb moves it forward to the end of the function prologue.

As for why debug information might affect how lldb determines where the end of the prologue is: it turns out the DWARF line table from the debug info has an "end of prologue" marker which lldb will happily use.  Whereas, if you don't have debug info, lldb falls back to scanning the instructions from the start of the function and matching them to "known prologue patterns".  The latter is more like educated guessing, whereas the compiler can know this precisely.  So the two computations do sometimes differ.

BTW, if you don't want this behavior, then do:

```
(lldb) break set -n <my_function> --skip-prologue 0
```